# Storybook throws: Cannot find module 'react/package.json'

Tags: reactjs, storybook, rollup

I'm developing a react library using rollup as a bundler.

When running storybook, I have the following error thrown by storybook:

> ERR! Error: Cannot find module 'react/package.json'

react and react-dom packages are listed as **peerDependencies** along with the *rollup-plugin-peer-deps-external* package in rollup to exclude them from being bundled with the library.

In my rollup config, I also put these packages in the external entry.

Can someone help, please?

Comment: are you using npm link, that can be an issue

Comment: I found a same problem, and yes I am using npm link.